# Finding $a_0, a_1, a_2$ such that $0< a_{0}+a_{1}\sin(x)+a_{2}\cos(x)<1$ holds for all $x \in \mathbb R$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inequality

I needed to find all values of $a_{0}$, $a_{1}$ and $a_{2}$ such that the inequality $$0< a_{0}+a_{1}\sin(x)+a_{2}\cos(x)<1$$
is satisfied for all $x \in \mathbb R $.

Since the maximum values of $\sin(x)$, and $\cos(x)$ are $1$, the above inequality can be written as $0<a_{0}+a_{1}+a_{2}<1$. Similarly, the minimum values of $\sin(x)$, and $\cos(x)$ are $-1$, the same inequality can be written as  $0<a_{0}-a_{1}-a_{2}<1$. Moreover, when $\sin(x)$ takes its maximum value and $\cos(x)$ takes its minimum value, the inequality becomes  $0<a_{0}+a_{1}-a_{2}<1$. And when $\sin(x)$ takes its minimum value and $\cos(x)$ takes its maximum value, the inequality becomes  $0<a_{0}-a_{1}+a_{2}<1$. Therefore, I end up with $8$ linear inequalities that define a polyhedron in 3D space. Is that argument correct?

Comment: Divide both sides by $\sqrt{a_1^2+a_2^2}$. For $a_1=a_2=0$ we have $0<a_0<1$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your solution, you talk about values of $x$ where $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ *simultaneously* attain maxima or minima. But in reality, there are no such $x$. Indeed, $\sin x$ attains its maxima and minima at $x = \pi (\tfrac 1 2 + n)$, whereas $\cos x$ attains its maxima and minima at $x = \pi n$. The maxima and minima of $\sin x$ are located at different points to the maxima and minima of $\cos x$!

Furthermore, you should be focused on finding the maxima and minima of $a_1 \sin x + a_2 \cos x$. The maxima and minima $a_1 \sin x + a_2 \cos x$ are not located at the same points as the maxima and minima of the individual functions $\sin x$ and $\cos x$.

My suggestion is to use the addition formula for the sine function to write
$$ a_0 + a_1 \sin x + a_2 \cos x = a_0 + \sqrt{a_1^2 + a_2^2} \sin(x + \phi).$$
Here, $\phi$ is an angle such that
$$ \cos \phi = \frac {a_1}{\sqrt{a_1^2 + a_2^2}}, \qquad \sin\phi = \frac {a_2}{\sqrt{a_1^2 + a_2^2}}.$$
Such an angle $\phi$ exists because the point $\left( \frac {a_1}{\sqrt{a_1^2 + a_2^2}}, \frac {a_2}{\sqrt{a_1^2 + a_2^2}} \right)$ lies on the unit circle.

It is clear that
$$ \text{max}_{x \in \mathbb R} \left( a_0 + \sqrt{a_1^2 + a_2^2} \sin(x + \phi) \right) = a_0 + \sqrt{a_1^2 + a_2^2}$$
and
$$ \text{min}_{x \in \mathbb R} \left( a_0 + \sqrt{a_1^2 + a_2^2} \sin(x + \phi) \right) = a_0 - \sqrt{a_1^2 + a_2^2}.$$

Thus, the inequality $0 < a_0 + a_1 \sin x + a_2 \cos x < 1$  holds for all $x \in \mathbb R$ if and only if
$$ a_0 - \sqrt{a_1^2 + a_2^2} > 0, \qquad a_0 + \sqrt{a_1^2 + a_2^2} < 1,$$
i.e. if and only if
$$ 0 < a_0 < 1, \qquad \sqrt{a_1^2 + a_2^2} < \text{min} \left\{ a_0, 1 - a_0 \right\}.$$

Answer (score 1):

I would use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality $$|a_1\cos x +a_2\sin x|\le \sqrt{a_1^2+a_2^2}$$ The inequality becomes equality if $\tan x=\pm {a_2\over a_1}.$ Hence the minimal value is equal $a_0-\sqrt{a_1^2+a_2^2},$ while the maximum value is equal $a_0+\sqrt{a_1^2+a_2^2}.$